# Need Help in calling SQL in ASP

Tags: sql, vbscript, asp-classic

Hi I am new to ASP and I am trying to build SQL on fly in my page.

```
 sSQL = "SELECT "
 sSQL = sSQL & " Message1,"
 sSQL = sSQL & " Message2"
 sSQL = sSQL & " FROM table1"
 sSQL = sSQL & " WHERE"
 sSQL = sSQL & " name = '" & customname & "'" 

Set serverobject = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
serverobject .Open sSQL, conn

message1 = serverobject ("Message1")
    message2 = serverobject ("Message2")

      response.Write message1
      response.Write message2
```

Here whats happening is **customname** is name entered by user and I am comparing with my **name** column in table **table1**.

If it matched then everything is working fine and I am getting proper result.

But if customname  doesn't match with name then I am getting this error :

**Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record.**

What I got to know if I should check for null somehow while calling query and if it contains result then only proceed. Can someone help me how can i achieve this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must check for rows before reading from the `recordset`, for example using `.eof`:

```
if (serverobject.eof) then
   ''// no matching rows
else
   message1 = serverobject("Message1")
   message2 = serverobject("Message2")
end if
```

Also as your not using a parametrized statement don't forget to sanitize the string in the `customname` variable.